# Not able to move .gitignore file from one directory to another

Tags: java, file, apache-commons

I am automating a particular process where in one of the steps I need to copy a `.gitignore` file from one directory to another.
I am using Apache's `FileUtils` class to achieve the same, however it is not able to recognise this particular file (it is although present in the folder). The code is working for other files.

Here is my code:

```
public void copyFile(String destinationPath, String file) throws IOException {

    ClassPathResource classPathResourceAPIUtils = new ClassPathResource(file);
    String fileName = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/"));
    InputStream inputStreamapiUtils = classPathResourceAPIUtils.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader readUtils = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreamapiUtils));
    List<String> utilsLines = readUtils.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
    FileUtils.writeLines(new File(destinationPath+fileName), utilsLines, false);
}
```

Comment: Why are you reading and writing files when you could actually **move** them? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html Dot-files are usually "hidden", but I don't think Java really cares about that, so something else seems like a problem here

Comment: My bad. I meant I tried to "copy" it, and not "move" it. Edited the question.

Comment: You can also copy files without reading their content https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you rewriting the files. Just use:

```
Files.move(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

or

```
Files.copy(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```